# Discord bot purge command - code error: TypeError: message.reply is not a function

Tags: javascript, discord.js

So, this my code for my discord bot. The purpose of it is to purge up to 100 messages, but whenever I try and use the "return message.reply" command, I get the error: "TypeError: message.reply is not a function" This is the code that I have:

```
var Discord = require('discord.js');
    
    
    exports.run = async(message, args) =>{
    
    
    
    
    
        if(!args[0]) return message.reply("please specify the amount of messages that you would like me to purge!")
        if(isNaN(args[0])) return message.reply('please enter a number after the command!')
    
        if(args[0] > 100) return message.reply('you cannot delete more than 100 messages at a time!')
        if(args[0] < 1) return message.reply('you cannot purge a number less than 1!')
    
        await message.channel.messages.fetch({limit: args[0]}).then(messages => {
            message.channel.bulkDelete(messages);
        });
    }
```

Comment: It looks as if you have a mistake in your message and command handler, it would be useful to see these before we can look at what you did wrong.

Comment: Adding to what Proto said - just add all of the relevant code you're using (i.e index.js/main.js) as well. You also don't need the top `require` line as this is a command file

Comment: Thank you! I figured it out, I appreciate it!